# Can we use Pandas merge in each use case where Pandas Join can be used?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

[Technical Question]

Earlier I used to think Pandas Join can be used for indexes and columns having same name in both data frame and
Pandas merge can be used only for columns having same or different name in both data frame but merge can't be used for indexes but now I came to know that using left_index and right_index we can perform combine data frames using index column in merge.
So is there any specify use case where only Pandas Join will work? Please share

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, `merge` is more versatile and can always replace `join`.

Comment: @mozway So there is no specific use case of join which merge can't do. As far you know. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any use case in which [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) cannot replace [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), which makes sense since [`join` uses `merge` internally](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L10404-L10425)

The opposite is not true, since `merge` handles columns and has extended functions (`indicator`).

##### Then why do we have `join`?

It's a convenience.

This is much easier to write `df1.join(df2)` than `df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)`.

There are several other examples in pandas functions. For instance [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) is a [wrapper around `pivot_table`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.0/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L711-L718), and [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) a [wrapper around `melt`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.0/pandas/core/reshape/melt.py#L488-L494).

Comment: Thanks for your research. Just wonder then why do we have Joins in pandas? It will be helpful if you can upvote my question.

Comment: @Anubhav it's a convenience. It's much easier to write `df1.join(df2)` than `df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)`. There are many other examples in pandas functions. For instance `crosstab` is a wrapper around `pivot_table`, and `wide_to_long` around `melt`.

Comment: NB. [You shouldn't request votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350915/can-i-request-for-vote-up). I usually vote for questions to which I answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your deep research